# Efficient Dictionary lookup

Tags: c++

For my C++ application, there is a requirement to check if a word is a valid English dictionary word or not. What is the best way to do it. Is there freely available dictionary that I can make use of. I just need a collection of all possible words. How to make this lookup least expensive. Do I need to hash it.

Comment: There are too many smaller questions in your post which don't really relate much to the title. Try to narrow down on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to the presence of a word list, it depends on the platform.
Under Linux, `/usr/share/dict/words` contains a list of English words
that might meet your needs.  Otherwise, there are doubtlessly such lists
available on the network.

Given the size of such lists, the most rapid access will be to load it
into a hash table. `std::unsorted_set`, if you have it; otherwise, many
C++ compilers come with a `hash_set`, although different compilers have
a slightly different interface for it, and put it in different
namespaces.  If that still has performance problems, it's possible to do
better if you know the number of entries in advance (so the table never
has to grow), and implement the hash table in an std::vector (or even a
C style array); handling collisions will be a bit more complicated,
however.

Another possibility would be a trie.  This will almost certainly result
in the least number of basic operations in the lookup, and is fairly
simple to implement.  Typical implementations will have very poor
locality, however, which could make it slower than some of the other
solutions in actual practice (or not—the only way to know is to
implement both and measure).

Comment: And in case `hash_set` is not available either, there is always `boost::unordered_set`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  Even if `hash_set` is available, `boost::unordered_set` might be preferable, since 1) it is portable, across all the compilers which Boost supports, and 2) it corresponds exactly to `std::unordered_set` (I think), which will make the migration to the standard easier when it becomes available.

Comment: I would prefer it indeed, however some people prefer compiler extensions to including Boost :)

Answer (score 7):

Use either a `std::set<std::string>` or a `std::unordered_set<std::string>`.  The latter is new in C++0x and may or may not be supported by your C++ Standard Library implementation; if it does not support it, it may include a `hash_set` of some kind:  consult your documentation to find out.

Which of these (`set`, which uses a binary search tree, and `unordered_set`, which uses a hashtable) is more efficient depends on the number of elements you are storing in the container and how your Standard Library implementation implements them.  Your best bet is to try both and see which performs better for your specific scenario.

Alternatively, if the list of words is fixed, you might consider using a sorted `std::vector` and using `std::binary_search` to find words in it.

Answer (score 3):

I actually did this a few months ago, or something close to this. You can probably find one online for free.

Like on this website: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Just put it in a text file, and compare words with what is on the list. It should be order n with n being the number of words in the list. Do you need the time complexity faster?

Hope this helps.